# Find an element exist in List using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I am pretty much working on the basics of jQuery, it could have done easily if it's in Java :P

```
var thread_list = [];
var feed_list = [];

$.each(json.messages, function(i, m) {
    if (m.replied_to_id == "") {
        alert(m.thread_id);
        thread_list.push(m.thread_id);
    }
});

$.each(json.references, function(i, r) {
    if (r.id exists in threadList) {  //how do I do this more effectively?
        feed_list.push(r.url);
    }
});
```

How to find an element exist in the List?

Comment: `threadList.indexOf(r.id) !== -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a modern browser you could use the `filter` function on `[]`.

```
var thread_list = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}];
var feed_list = [];

function exists(arr,prop,val){
    var threads = arr.filter(function(e){
        return e[prop] == val;
    });
    return !!threads.length;
}


alert(exists(thread_list, "id", 4)); //returns false
alert(exists(thread_list, "id", 2)); //returns true
```

**JS FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/7vTWj/

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.inArray(r.id , threadList); //give 0 to any positive number if exist otherwise give -1
```

reference **[inarray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)**

Comment: `jQuery.inArray()` may also return `0` which will be treated falsy in `if` condition. So just make sure to check it like -   
`if(jQuery.inArray(r.id , threadList)!=-1)`

Comment: no by 0 it gives index position at o bse array index start form 0  for more detail see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: If the element is the first element, using your statement will return 0 which will be treated as false in an `if` condition.
You can refer the same link too.  They too have specifically mentioned to check it against -1. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `indexOf()`:

```
if (threadList.indexOf(r.id) != -1)
```

In case you're using an old browser that doesn't have `indexOf()`, you can use `jQuery.inArray()`:

```
if ($.inArray(r.id, threadList) != -1)
```

Comment: Never forget almighty `IE` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.each(json.references, function(i, r) {
    if (threadlist.indexOf(r)!=-1) {  
        feed_list.push(r.url);
    }
});
```

In java, actually you would create a JSONOBject for the original json and then get the json threadlist as a JSONArray and then convert it to an actual array to check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
if ( $.inArray(r.id, threadList ) != 1 )
```